# Description not working email sent dynamics 365 HUB

Tags: dynamic, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

The Field Description of entity email  doesn't show in Hub Dynamics 365. Before I send the email the description appears, but after I click on send email the description not working. This problem only happens in HUB. I tried disabling all javascript but the problem continued and it does not generate a log error in the plugin or in JS, only not show the description. Guys I'm sorry about my English because it's  terrible. 
CRM version 9.0.9.4.

[Print email sent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDdPk.png)

[Creating email before send email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05eCp.png)

[Picture with comparing Hub and form default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQTtV.png)

[Picture of audit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVkvM.png)

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the same field? Check the audit

Comment: Hello @ArunVinoth, I checked out the audit and the field is correct. I added two picture in my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

my prolem was solved, I applied all updates avalible https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3142345/microsoft-dynamics-365-onpremise-cumulative-updates